# allauth Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, selenium, tdd

I am using allauth and have my login/logout functionality working properly on the site (I can login/logout/register successfully in Selenium functional tests aswell).

My problem is when I try to do unit tests to check the correct templates are being used for any view with the @login_required decorator.

For example:

View:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

Unit test:

```
class ProfileTest(TestCase):

    def test_uses_profile_template(self):
        # it makes no difference if this is commented out or not
        #class MockUser:
        #    is_authenticated = True

        response = self.client.get('/users/profile')
        #response.user = MockUser()
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'profile.html')
```

My urls:

```
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

And the error msg:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name
```

My biggest confusion comes from the fact everything works fine in functional tests and when using the site normally.
Thank you.

--- ANSWER ---
I later found how to do this. For anyone else stuck, this worked:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

def test_uses_profile_template(self):
        user = User.objects.create()
        self.client.force_login(user)
        response = self.client.get('/profile/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'users/profile.html')
```